# Xamarin google Native Ads IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, admob

I am trying to implement Native ads in xamarin it works fine with android but I have a problem with ios
Here is my code

```
public class AdMobNativeAdRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.NativeAdView, UnifiedNativeAdView>, IAdLoaderDelegate, IUnifiedNativeAdDelegate, IUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate, IVideoControllerDelegate

    {

        
        public UnifiedNativeAdView nativeAdView = null;
        public void DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd(AdLoader adLoader, UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd)
        {

            // A unified native ad has loaded, and can be displayed.
            nativeAd.Delegate = this;
            //  The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be present in every native ad.
            nativeAdView.NativeAd = nativeAd;
            if (nativeAdView.HeadlineView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.HeadlineView= new UILabel();
            }
            (nativeAdView.HeadlineView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Headline;
            if (nativeAdView.MediaView == null) {
                nativeAdView.MediaView = new MediaView();
             }
            if (nativeAdView.MediaView.MediaContent == null)
            {
                nativeAdView.MediaView.MediaContent = new MediaContent();
            }
            nativeAdView.MediaView.MediaContent = nativeAd.MediaContent;
            nativeAdView.MediaView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill;
            if (nativeAdView.BodyView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.BodyView = new UILabel();
            }
            (nativeAdView.BodyView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Body;
            nativeAdView.BodyView.Hidden = nativeAd.Body == null;
            if (nativeAdView.CallToActionView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.CallToActionView = new UIButton();
            }
       
            (nativeAdView.CallToActionView as UIButton).SetTitle(nativeAd.CallToAction,UIControlState.Normal);
            nativeAdView.CallToActionView.Hidden = nativeAd.CallToAction == null;

            if (nativeAdView.IconView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.IconView = new UIImageView();
            }
            (nativeAdView.IconView as UIImageView).Image = nativeAd.Icon.Image;
            nativeAdView.IconView.Hidden = nativeAd.Icon == null;
            if (nativeAdView.StoreView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.StoreView = new UILabel();
            }
            (nativeAdView.StoreView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Store;
            nativeAdView.StoreView.Hidden = nativeAd.Store == null;

            if (nativeAdView.PriceView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.PriceView = new UILabel();
            }
            (nativeAdView.PriceView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Price;

            nativeAdView.PriceView.Hidden = nativeAd.Price == null;
            if (nativeAdView.AdvertiserView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.AdvertiserView = new UILabel();
            }
            if (nativeAdView.StoreView==null)
            {
                nativeAdView.StoreView = new UILabel();
            }
            (nativeAdView.StoreView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Store;


            (nativeAdView.AdvertiserView as UILabel).Text = nativeAd.Advertiser;
            nativeAdView.AdvertiserView.Hidden = nativeAd.Advertiser == null;
            nativeAdView.CallToActionView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            nativeAdView.NativeAd = nativeAd;
            try
            {
               nativeAdView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
                SetNativeControl(nativeAdView);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        
        [Export("adLoaderDidFinishLoading:")]
        void DidFinishLoading(AdLoader adLoader)
        {
            // The adLoader has finished loading ads, and a new request can be sent.
        }

        public void DidFailToReceiveAd(AdLoader adLoader, RequestError error)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.NativeAdView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            try
            {
                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        e.OldElement.Content=null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }

                    
                    SetNativeControl(nativeAdView);
                }

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    if (Control == null)
                    {
                        // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
                        CreateAdView();
                        try
                        {
                            e.NewElement.Content = null;
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {


                        }

                        SetNativeControl(nativeAdView);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        AdLoader  adLoader;
        private void CreateAdView()
        {

            //if (Element == null) return;
            var multipleAdsOptions = new MultipleAdsAdLoaderOptions { NumberOfAds = 1 };
            adLoader = new AdLoader("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511", GetVisibleViewController(), new[] { AdLoaderType.UnifiedNative }, new[] { multipleAdsOptions })
            {
                Delegate = this
            };

            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            request.TestDevices = new string[] { Request.SimulatorId };



            if (nativeAdView == null)
            {
                nativeAdView = new UnifiedNativeAdView();
            };

            try
            {
                adLoader.LoadRequest(request);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Loading: " + adLoader.IsLoading);
        }
        private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
            foreach (var window in windows)
            {
                if (window.RootViewController != null)
                {
                    return window.RootViewController;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Every thing is working as anticipated and I receive the ad and the event DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd fires but I get an empty ad although when I debug the code I see that the content of the ad is not empty and the control color is green so the control is loaded but why it doesn't show the ad content
Please can anyone help is solving this

Comment: Here are some common reasons for ads not showing https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en